# iPhone - a question about drawRect

Tags: iphone

Suppose that instead a UIView I subclass a UIImageView and assign a background image to it, like in

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: //... bla bla
```

and then I implement a drawRect method and use it to draw stuff on the image.

My question is:

1. will the stuff being drawn on the
   image itself or in a kind of "layer"
   totally independent?
2. if the later is true, how do I
   access this "layer"?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you override drawRect, the stuff will be drawn on the image itself. Every `UIImage` is backed by a `CALayer`, so you're really drawing everything onto that. Access it with

```
[image layer];
```

Comment: Hi, by "layer" do you mean image?

Comment: thanks. As I suspected. The image itself is modified. But why should I call [super drawRect]? Isn't this method called automatically when the imageView is allocated?

Comment: Whoops, my fault, just erased that part. I forgot that drawRect does nothing by default. Sorry about that... Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 2):

You should subclass UIView, not UIImageView if you need custom drawing.

From the UIImageView class reference

> The UIImageView class is optimized to draw its images to the display. UIImageView will not call drawRect: a subclass. If your subclass needs custom drawing code, it is recommended you use UIView as the base class.